# Block http request on AngularJS

Tags: angularjs, http

I guess similar questions were asked about this issue but I couldn't find the answer I am looking for.

I have the following code

```
$http.get('/admin/data').then(function(response) {
    $scope.somethingToShowToTheUser = response.data.newVisitors;
});
```

The question is how can I block the http request before this is actually shown to the user?

I read about promises but I don't see how it can help me in blocking this request.

Thanks

Comment: What do you mean by "block the http request"?

Comment: you already using the promise with $http ( by using 'then' ). if you want to check a condition use it  inside the then `$http.get('/admin/data').then(function(response) {
 if(showtouser){
  $scope.somethingToShowToTheUser = response.data.newVisitors;
 }else{ tmp = response.data.newVisitors;}
});`

Comment: does "block the http request" means cancelling the requests as of your context?

Comment: No, maybe I don't understand something here but lets say I get the data from a really slow server. In the HTML I do {{somethingToShowToTheUser}} somewhere. wouldn't the HTML be loaded before the data is retrieved from the server?

Comment: @Assafasdasdas i have answered trying my best to explain, hope i make sense with my answer

Comment: Look into using the [ng-if directive](https://docs.angularjs.org/api/ng/directive/ngIf) or [ng-show directive](https://docs.angularjs.org/api/ng/directive/ngShow) to delay showing HTML until data arrives from the server.